# Data set query change before chart rendering (BIRT reports)

Tags: birt

I am brand new to BIRT reports, and I have a problem where i need to change the data set query text before the rendering of a chart. There will be multiple charts on this report with the same data set, but a modified parameter in the query text.

Is this possible with Chart event handling? Below is an example of what i am looking to do. Thanks in advance

```
/**
 * Called before populating the series dataset using the DataSetProcessor.
 *
 * @param series
 *            Series
 * @param idsp
 *            IDataSetProcessor
 * @param icsc
 *            IChartScriptContext
 */

function beforeDataSetFilled( series, idsp, icsc )
{

this.queryText = "select from table where parameter = '"+params["Data"].value+"'"


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with a dataSet parameter in the chart's dataSet binding.

You would create your dataSet with your query and leave the parameter unset:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter = ?
```

And then in the chart's dataSet parameter binding, set it to the parameter you want.

[image]